# jar file for JPA 2.0

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

```
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
```

I've created a JPA project where I try to user the above classes but I'm unable to find what jar I'm missing for them. Please guide me.

Comment: a persistence provider. What do you want? Hibernate, EclipseLink, OpenJPA?

Comment: Not a persistence provider. Its the jpa2.jar he needs. The implementation should not really be providing that themselves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the Geronimo specs JPA2 jar
http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec/1.0-PFD2/
There is still no official JPA2.jar

Comment: What's wrong with the one of the RI (EclipseLink 2.0) which has been released in the same time as Java EE 6?

Comment: Who said anything is "wrong" with some companies own provided jar to include javax.persistence classes? Theirs presumably is up to PFD2 level of the spec. The fact is that there is currently no "official" jpa2.jar ... stored in Maven2 repos under "javax/persistence/persistence-api/2.0", hence using the Geronimo specs jar (or some other that people can find) is the way to go until SUN/Oracle finally provide one. The ones under EclipseLink are "EclipseLink version of javax.persistence" only

Comment: But what makes the case of Geronimo jar different? Why should I prefer this jar over the one from the RI?

Comment: I said "try the Geronimo specs jar", since that provides an Apache 2 licensed spec jar to use, and it gets the user beyond his problem. It's license is the most liberal around. It's also the only one in the main Maven2 repo IIRC. What is an "RI" ? its simply a proof of concept that the spec is implementable; comes with no magic blessing or anything. Use what you wish at the end of the day

Answer (score 5):

EclipseLink provides the JPA 2.0 Reference Implementation which is officially out since Java EE 6 is out. You'll find these classes in the jars bundled in [eclipselink-2.0.0.v20091127-r5931.zip](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/rt/eclipselink/releases/2.0.0/eclipselink-2.0.0.v20091127-r5931.zip). If you are looking for a Maven repo, have a look at [this page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven).

Answer (score 5):

A slightly better answer (since 2011) is to use the one from maven central, i.e.,

```
org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1-Final
```

OR

```
<groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1.Final</version>
```

See: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final/

For all the available versions, especially the latest, see http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/

Answer (score 3):

Here is hibernate-jpa-2.0

http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.0.Final/

Answer (score 0):

These files are found in the [javax.persistence](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/persistence/javax.persistence/2.1.1/javax.persistence-2.1.1.jar) jar file.  The Eclipse version of the [javax.persistence](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/persistence/javax.persistence/2.1.1/javax.persistence-2.1.1.jar) jar file can be found on [Maven Central](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2).  Or you can add the following dependency in your project's `pom.xml` file to get Maven to pull it down for you.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```